# How to test a service when DOCUMENT is injected as a dependency?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, mocking, jasmine, angular-test

I have an Angular service that is dependent on DOCUMENT:

```
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document) {}
```

I want to add tests for this service. I don't use any methods of document at this service and only pass it to a method to add event handlers.

How should I test this service? Should I mock DOCUMENT? If so, how?

Comment: If you're writing unit tests, the answer is yes, you mock document. You add it as a provider to your testing module.

Comment: Tnx, can you produce an example? @WillAlexander

Comment: If you never use any of its methods, you can simply provide it as `{ provide: DOCUMENT, useValue: {} }`.

Comment: Are you sure I have to mock it?!

Comment: It's a unit test. You never use real dependencies.